# Android studio http components

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to assemble debug apk with these dependencies in gradle:

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
```

Gradle build runs with no problem but when I try to assemble .apk then I get an error saying

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug]
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:compileLint
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:checkReleaseManifest
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:MemorizingTrustManager:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:compileLint
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:checkReleaseManifest
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libs:openpgp-api-lib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132301Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComKyleduoSwitchbuttonLibrary128Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareConversationsLibsMemorizingTrustManagerUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareConversationsLibsOpenpgpApiLibUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDeTimroesAndroidEnhancedListView034Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareMeLeolinShortcutBadger113Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareOrgWhispersystemsAxolotlAndroid134Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareOrgWhispersystemsCurve25519Android024Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\AndroidProjects\Conversations\build\outputs\apk\Conversations-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    Origin 1: D:\AndroidProjects\Conversations\libs\httpcore-4.4.4.jar
    Origin 2: D:\AndroidProjects\Conversations\libs\httpclient-4.5.1.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
    File 1: D:\AndroidProjects\Conversations\libs\httpcore-4.4.4.jar
    File 2: D:\AndroidProjects\Conversations\libs\httpclient-4.5.1.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.664 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

it looks like there are some duplicate classes in those jar but I need to include both of them because I need component from both of them. Is there any way to ignore this error and build apk anyway?

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, I thought that if I ignore it then my dependencies will be ignored too but it works